# apscheduler at 90 second intervals?

Tags: apscheduler

Is it possible to set an apscheduler cron job to run at 90 second intervals?  (I have 40 machines that I'd like to schedule evenly over an hour without hard coding time info into the script). I've tried various kinds of this:

```html
job = sched.add_cron_job(_test, minute='*/1', second='30')
job = sched.add_cron_job(_test, minute='*', second='90')
```

Comment: Do you mean to start a cron job at a particular time and run it indefinitely with 90 seconds interval?

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
job = sched.add_interval_job(_test, seconds=90)
```

Comment: seconds=90 refers to the nth second in a minute. So this would read 'the 90th second of every minute', which of course you can't have.

Comment: Note that I used `add_interval_job()`, not `add_cron_job()`.

Comment: It should be noted that the current scheduler API does not have either of these methods, but `add_job()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

#### Based on your question you want to start a cron job at a particular time and run it indefinitely with 90 seconds interval. You can achieve this by  [`combining triggers`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/combining.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.combining)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import AndTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger


def _test():
    print("code comes here")


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

#  Runs on 2019-12-30 at 5:30 (am) & repeats every 90 seconds interval
trigger = AndTrigger([IntervalTrigger(seconds=90),
                      CronTrigger(start_date='2019-12-30', hour=5, minute=30)])

scheduler.add_job(_test, trigger)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Combining IntervalTrigger and CronTrigger is almost always a bad idea, as they virtually never coincide (cron jobs do not produce microseconds while interval triggers practically always do).

Answer (score -1):

Interval code example:

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(ClassTest, 'interval', seconds=90)
sched.start()
```

Comment: As I posted above, the value after "seconds" isn't how many seconds elapse, but which second (between 0-59) of a minute the job should run. Entering 90 throws an error for me, though may not have at time of OP.